# Red exclamation mark in folder icon

Tags: android

I have a problem. I have read another similar tips but i have not found solution. I have a project with exclamation mark in the folder icon.

Looking in the Java Build Path I have found that there is a problem with Android Dependences google-play-service_lib.jar. The error is:
/...../extras/google/gogle_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/bin (missing)

It says bin folder is missing. I have looked in the path and there is no bin folder. I have tried delete the library and after that reinstall it but it did not work.

Could anybody help me?

New: I have attached a snapshot with the problem.
[image]
Thanks a lot.

SOLVED: I have solved it when I have located the google_play_services library in the same drive as my project. Thank you all!

Comment: What do you mean by 'reinstall'? Specifying the right path to the google play services folder should solve a lot

Comment: I have reinstalled google play services throw Android SDK manger but it did ot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this was solved by having the google_play_services library in the same drive as my eclipse workspace.

Comment: but the android sdk manager installs libraries where it wants, It has a default path to install it. Could I change it to my workspace?

Comment: I have tried your solution and it worked for me. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Of course! How can I do it? I do not find the option

Comment: You see where it's written "For me this was...", right to the left of that are 2 buttons: one over the zero and one under it. The top button is upvote, and down button is downvote :)

Comment: Oh too easy! :) I am sorry but the system says that I do not have enough reputations points to vote up.... I will vote up later when I have points.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the menu:

Project > clean > clean all projects

EDIT:
Based on the new snapshot, it seems your library is missing.
Open your SDK manager and make sure the appropriate library is installed (Google Play Services). Then open your project settings and in the library section, remove and add your library again. Then clean and build your project.

Comment: I have clened all projects but the problem still continuous.

Comment: Make sure the library is installed and properly added to your project.

Comment: I imported the library by File->import and selecting the folder downloaded by android sdk manager. I want to remove it from the project and then import it again. How can I delete it from the project? 

Note: In project->propierties->java build path in "Android devependences" i can not remove google-play-serices because it is not available.

Comment: In your project properties click the second option which says "Android". There should be two options - build target and library. Try to experiment with that. Check this link for more info - http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

This means that some file is missing.

I suppose you imported the project into the eclipse, rather than making new project. If you have imported the project, then you should add the missing class or project, then your red icon will go away.

I have face this problem.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: I have reinstalled google play services throw Android SDK manger but it did ot work.

Comment: You have screenshots for me?

Comment: I am so sorry but I do not have enough reputation to add images yet.

Comment: Now I have enough reputation points and now I am able to upload images. In the original post there is a snapshot with the problem. Thanks.

Comment: No it isn't. In path "android-sdk_20.0.3/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/" there is not bin folder. There are the following folders: libs, res and src but google-play-services_lib.jar is not in these folders.
I think this structure of folders are made by android sdk manager when I install google play service. I tried to resintall twice google play services but i have the same structure.